# MySQL combining records from two tables with join and without

Tags: mysql, sql, join

What's the difference between these two queries:

```
SELECT `threads`.`id` AS `threads.id` , `posts`.`id` , `posts`.`content`
FROM `threads`
JOIN `posts` ON `threads`.`id` = `posts`.`thread_id`
```

And

```
SELECT `threads`.`id` AS `threads.id` , `posts`.`id` , `posts`.`content`
FROM `threads` , `posts`
WHERE `threads`.`id` = `posts`.`thread_id`
```

They both return same data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WHERE` clause filtering result set which is returned by `JOIN`, so this is a difference.

As long as you are using `INNER JOIN` there is no differences neither performance nor execution plan, in case of any `OUTER JOIN` query would produce different execution plan.

Also pay attention to what is said in the [MySql online doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

> Generally, you should use the ON clause for conditions that specify
>   how to join tables, and the WHERE clause to restrict which rows you
>   want in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

One uses ANSI Joins the other is using pre-ansi style join.  MOST DB engines will compile them into the same execution plan.

Comment: In the 70's when I started with SQL the 2nd one was the only join possible. Then Chris Date "invented" other JOINS and that's where the new syntax was brought in.

Comment: Yep; both work fine.  The new bread of programmer is being told the "RIGHT" way to do it is to use ANSI.  But I've found both typically work and SOMETIMES the pre-ANSI joins will actually be faster and vice-versa.  I don't know why they generate different execution plans with different performances; but sometimes they just do.

Answer (score 1):

**In one word: Readability.**

Running the following code:

```
create table #threads (
id int
)

create table #posts (
id int,
thread_id int,
content varchar(10)
)

insert into #threads values (1)
insert into #threads values (2)
insert into #posts values (1, 1, 'Stack')
insert into #posts values (2, 2, 'OverFlow')


SELECT #threads.id AS 'threads.id' , #posts.id , #posts.content
FROM #threads
JOIN #posts ON #threads.id = #posts.thread_id

SELECT #threads.id AS 'threads.id' , #posts.id , #posts.content
FROM #threads, #posts
WHERE #threads.id = #posts.thread_id

drop table #threads
drop table #posts
```

in https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new you'll get the same execution plan :)

*The only real difference* is that `inner join` is **ANSI** and the `from #threads, #posts` is **Transact-SQL syntax.**

Answer (score 0):

There might be difference in internal implementation of those queries, but I doubt it. 
I'd personally prefer `JOIN` because it makes execution plan more obvious.